# Codeigniter: 'Undefined index' when trying to pass a single value from an array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm setting `$data['Milestone']` using a model;

```
$data['Milestone'] = $this->Work_model->GetMilestone($this->UserID, $this->MilestoneID);
```

This returns a few rows from SQL, I need to pass one specific row to the view, here's what I've tried;

```
$this->pageData = array('pageTitle' => $data['Milestone']['MilestoneName']);
$this->load->view('includes/Header_view', $this->pageData);
```

On the page I get this error:

> Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: MilestoneName Filename:
>   controllers/Views_controller.php Line Number: 86

How do I pass only MilestoneName to the view?

Edit: Model as requested:

```
public function GetMilestone($UserID, $MilestoneID){
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM FYP_Milestones
                            INNER JOIN FYP_Modules ON FYP_Milestones.ModuleID = FYP_Modules.ID
                            INNER JOIN FYP_Accounts ON FYP_Modules.PathwayID = FYP_Accounts.PathwayID
                            LEFT JOIN FYP_Submissions ON FYP_Milestones.MilestoneID = FYP_Submissions.MatchMilestoneID AND FYP_Submissions.UserID = $UserID 
                            LEFT JOIN FYP_MilestoneNotes ON FYP_Milestones.MilestoneID = FYP_MilestoneNotes.NotesMilestoneID AND FYP_MilestoneNotes.UserID = $UserID AND FYP_MilestoneNotes.NotesMilestoneID = $MilestoneID
                            WHERE FYP_Milestones.MilestoneID = $MilestoneID
                            AND FYP_Accounts.UserID = $UserID                                
                            LIMIT 1");
  return $query->result();
}
```

Image of SQL result: [image]

Comment: Are you sure that Work_model->GetMilestone return an array ?

Comment: post code of model function `GetMilestone`

Comment: 100% sure, I've used it later on by passing $data to another view, but I need this variable for the page header and being echoed in the meta tags.

Comment: Try just `echo $pageTitle` in your view :)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing but i'm getting this error

Comment: WE can't help you untill unless you post your model function!!

Comment: `->result()` return object not an array!! check https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html

Comment: Can you do `echo '<pre style="border:1px solid; text-align:left; background:grey; font-size:16px; padding:5px;color:black; display:none;">'
, print_r($data, true), '<hr/></pre> ';` ? Probably it's not an array but an object